# How to push my project from Eclipse to my Github?

Tags: eclipse, github

I created a project on Eclipse and I've working on it.

Some days ago I was trying to save it on Github.

Then I did like this:

Team -> Share Project -> Git -> Create

Now, there is a label next to the name of the project: [MyProject master].

I've already did some commits but when I go to my github using a browser, I can't find my project there.

So, how do I make it appears in https://github.com/myuser ?

Please help me. I am new on Git. I am still learning its concepts.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I found my solution here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1kXlahkwd4